# Scalar Triple Product

Tags: vector-spaces, solid-geometry

Prove that if $\:$$\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, $\vec{c}$ and $\vec{r}$ are any four vectors and if $[\vec{x} \: \vec{y} \: \vec{z}]$ is Scalar Triple product, Then

$$[\vec{a} \: \vec{b} \: \vec{r}]\vec{c}+[\vec{b} \: \vec{c} \: \vec{r}]\vec{a}+[\vec{c} \: \vec{a} \: \vec{r}]\vec{b}=[\vec{a} \: \vec{b} \: \vec{c}]\vec{r}$$

My Try: Let $$F(\vec{r})=[\vec{a} \: \vec{b} \: \vec{r}]\vec{c}+[\vec{b} \: \vec{c} \: \vec{r}]\vec{a}+[\vec{c} \: \vec{a} \: \vec{r}]\vec{b}$$

where $F(.)$ is a function.

Put $\vec{r}=\vec{a}$ Then

$$F(\vec{a})=[\vec{a} \: \vec{b} \: \vec{c}]\vec{a}$$ Put $\vec{r}=\vec{b} $ Then

$$F(\vec{b})=[\vec{a} \: \vec{b} \: \vec{c}]\vec{b}$$ Similarly

put $\vec{r}=\vec{c}$ Then

$$F(\vec{c})=[\vec{a} \: \vec{b} \: \vec{c}]\vec{c}$$

From the three equations above, we can observe that $F(.)$ is a linear function with slope $[\vec{a} \: \vec{b} \: \vec{c}]$ Hence

$$F(\vec{r})=[\vec{a} \: \vec{b} \: \vec{c}]\vec{r}$$

I feel this approach is quite informal..can any one give me better way to prove this.

Comment: This seems fine. However it needs minor adaptation for the case where $a,b,c$ are not linearly independent (very easy - then we have a,b,c = 0)$. Also note that “scalar triple product” is an unusual term, “determinant” is better; also, your problem only works in dimension three.